# In JS what does processMethod = processMethod || function(){}; do?

Tags: javascript, shorthand

I am reading through some javascript code, and I have seen a lot of code that looks like this:

```
processMethod = processMethod || function(){};
```

it's usually found inside a function. I believe it's a shorthand code, but I am not sure what it does.

Does it check to see if processMethod has a value, and if it doesn't declares it as a function that can be defined later?

Comment: means if `processMethod` doesn't exists, just create a an empty function to prevent `processMethod -- undefined error.`

Comment: Sorry #Raymond Chen. I had no idea how to ask the question, or even what terms to search for before posting it.

Comment: Yeah, the important part was punctuation, which SO doesn't know how to search for.

Comment: @RaymondChen, @gdaniel: [`[javascript] what does "||" do`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+what+does+%22||%22+do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In words:

```
if there is no processMethod, create it empty.
```

`||` works with booleans, so it checks if the first operand `processMethod` has a boolean-equivalent. If processMethod is defined and not null, the boolean-equivalent is `true`. If processMethod is undefined or null, the boolean-equivalent is `false`. In the false-case, `||` looks for a boolean-equivalent of the second-operand, its not null so its boolean-equivalent is `true`.

`false || true` resolves to `true` so processMethod becomes `function(){}`.

**Btw** `function(){}` is a empty function whom used to not throw a error on `processMethod()`

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Still learning shorthand codes.

Answer (score 1):

It essentially checks whether it exists or not. If it doesn't exist, assign it.

```
function doSomething(o) {
    o = o || {};
}
```

In the above case, it checks whether a value for `o` was passed. If not it assigns an empty object to it.

Comment: In this case `doSomething(0)` may unfortunately changed to `{}`.

Comment: Technically, but chances are if you're expecting an object you won't get 0 passed.

Comment: Correct, its also matched to the OP's concrete question.